# How to include modal for each iteration in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, pug

I'm creating a blogging engine with Node.js and jade, and iterating through each post, giving them a button with the ability to delete the post. For whatever reason, when I click on the button, It only provides me a modal with the ID for the last post, only giving me the ability to delete the last post, no matter which button I click. Can someone give me an explanation? Here's my code:

```
      each post in postsList
        div#post-container(class='container-fluid')
          .row
            .col-md-6
              a(href='/blog/posts/#{post._id}')  
                h2 #{post.title}
                h4 Date and Time posting
                img#post-img(src=urlList[i])
            .col-md-1.offset-md-5
              if isAdmin
                div(id='#{post._id}Modal' style='display:none;')
                  p #{post._id}
                  // Modal content
                  .modal-content
                    .modal-header
                      span.closeDeletePost ×
                      h2 Modal Header
                    .modal-body
                      p Are you sure you want to delete post?
                    .modal-footer
                      a(href="api/blog/posts/#{post._id}/delete")                          
                        button Yes
                      button.closeDeletePost No

                button.xxx(id='#{post._id}') X 

                script.
                  var postId = "#{post._id}"
                  // Get the modal
                  var deletePostModal = document.getElementById(postId + 'Modal');

                  // Get the button that opens the modal
                  var deletePostBtn = document.getElementById(postId);

                  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                  var closeDeletePost = document.getElementsByClassName("closeDeletePost")[0];

                  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
                  deletePostBtn.onclick = function() {
                        deletePostModal.style.display = "block";
                  };

                  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                  closeDeletePost.onclick = function() {
                       deletePostModal.style.display = "none";
                  };



// Modal ID output for all buttons is 5b64a45fe1f29c1f1448c21f
// I can only delete last post, no matter which post btn is clicked
// I want to delete any post, according to which btn I click
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript there are only two scopes; global and function scope. All of your `var`'s share the same global scope, which is an issue. For each loop iteration, the script code executes in the same scope. All the variables are changing, and when the loop finishes they will each be equal to whatever they were in the last iteration. Now for example, the variable `deletePostBtn` in every `.onClick` function references the `deletePostBtn` variable in the global scope. By the time you click a button, the for loop has finished and the `deletePostBtn` variable will be equal to the value it was assigned in the last loop iteration. So now every `.onClick` function references that same value.

Wrapping the logic in a function will create a new local/function scope. Now instead of the `postId` updating every iteration, it will be scoped to the function at the time of the iteration and remain the same in the future.

See the below code example. I simplified the code down to the crux of the issue.

**Before:** (Not working)

```
each post in postsList
    button(id='#{post._id}') #{post.title} 

    script.
            var postId = "#{post._id}"
            var deletePostBtn = document.getElementById(postId);
            deletePostBtn.onclick = function() {
                deletePostBtn.style.display = "none";
            };
```

**After:** (Working)

```
each post in postsList
    button(id='#{post._id}') #{post.title} 

    script.
            function createOnClick(postId) {
                var deletePostBtn = document.getElementById(postId);
                deletePostBtn.onclick = function() {
                        deletePostBtn.style.display = "none";
                };
            }
            createOnClick("#{post._id}")
```

Comment: Since my rank won't let me upvote, I'll send a simple 'Thank you'. It worked, cheers

Comment: @Forrest no worries glad you got it working. Also, can click the tick under the voting buttons to accept this as an answer to your question. It's used to indicate the question has been resolved.